# C# Changing Form1's PictureBox image to image from OpenFileDialog image selection in Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change the image currently presented in the Form1 picture box to a new image I select thru openFileDialog in Form2.

Can't seem to make it work. Help is highly appreciated, thank you.

Code: (Related functions)

```
**Form1.cs**

   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Initializing first form:
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(Image newImage)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        picBtn.Image = newImage;
    }

    //This function is activated if the picture button was clicked:
    private void picBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();

    }
}

**Form2.cs**

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    //Initializing second form:
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //This function is activated if the image upload button was clicked:
    private void imageUploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //New file dialog object:
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        //Accept images for files only:
        dialog.Filter= "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        Image newImage = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);
        Form1 form1 = new Form1(newImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you expect to change something in a `Form1` instance that is already displayed, how can creating a new `Form1` instance and doing something to that possibly help?

Comment: Setting a Form Property or field will not tickle the PBox to display the new image. You need to either set it directly, e.g. by making the Pbox public or by creating an updateImage function you call. The code __could__ work, but do you really want to have __two__ Form1s open??? You still would have to __show__ the new instance..

Comment: Be nice: There is NO reason to downvote!

Comment: As @TaW said: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: Thank you jmcilhinney and Taw. Taw, I just want Form1 to remain open, but change its PictureBox to the picture I upload thru OpenFileDialog in Form2... It seems like no function in Form1 ,even if it's public, is known to Form2, and that's why updateImage is not working for me as a new Form1 function...  Do you have a new solution or a clearer explanation of your current solution? Thank you.

PS: Yea, I don't know why they downvoted my question, I genuinely looked for a solution to my problem in Stack Overflow, but didn't find anything similar...

Comment: Since you already know about the trick to pass an object into a new Form via the constructor, why not pass the PictureBox into Form2? Now it has access and can set the Image directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help TaW

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have multiple *instances* of a `Form1` . Imagine `Form1` was an apple, and `Form2` a orange. You have your apple on screen, which in `picBtn_Click` tells the computer to now also display an orange.

This orange, in `imageUploadBtn_Click`, tells the computer to create a `new Apple` containing the image you selected. However, you're not telling the *existing* apple to display it, and you're not asking that your second apple be shown on screen either.

Apologies for the strange analogy, but I hope it helps. What you want is for `Form2` to become aware of the existing `Form1`. You could do this by having the `Form2` constructor take a `Form1` when it's created:

In `Form2`:

```
private readonly Form1 _apple;

//Initializing second form:
public Form2(Form1 apple)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _apple = apple;
}

//This function is activated if the image upload button was clicked:
private void imageUploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //New file dialog object:
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    //Accept images for files only:
    dialog.Filter= "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
    dialog.ShowDialog();
    Image newImage = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);
    // now, instead of creating a second instance of Form1,
    // pass the image to the existing instance.
    _apple.UpdatePicture(newImage);
}
```

You'll need to create a `public` method on `Form1` called `UpdatePicture` but I leave that to you. You'll also need to have `Form1` pass itself to `Form2` when it creates `Form2`, which can be done like this:

`Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);`

Please note, whilst this will work, we try to avoid *coupling* UI elements together like this. It will work, but there are some more complicated mechanics such as [MVVM](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364485/MVVM-Model-View-ViewModel-Patte) that might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something like this...

Change your `Form1.cs` method to like this.
In here, I remove your `Form1(Image newImage)` method and add a new public method called `public void ChangePicImg(Image newImage)`.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void ChangePicImg(Image newImage)
{
    picBtn.Image = newImage;
}

private void picBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 form2 = new Form2();
   form2.ShowDialog();    
}
```

Also, change your `Form2` like this.

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void imageUploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
    dialog.ShowDialog();
    Image newImage = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);

    Form1 frm1 = (Form1)System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"]; //Enter the Form1 name here
    frm1.ChangePicImg(newImage);
}
```

`["Form1"]` = Replace the Form1 with your Form1 name.

Comment: I hadn't considered using `OpenForms`, fair point. Is it considered preferable over the approach I've shown or just an alternative? (Been a long time since I did WinForms).

Comment: This is just an alternative. I do not know whether this approach is recommended or not.

Comment: Thank you very much D T, it worked. For all future same problem people, last line of code should be frm1.ChangePicImg(newImage); Thank you also Smudge